# Questions becoming statements

Tags: punctuation, sentence, syntactic-analysis

Sometimes there is an interesting effect when you convert a question into a statement, though this does seem somewhat modern. For example,

> What the heck.

as opposed to

> What the heck?

or even

> What the heck!

Or consider [this statement](http://nursesinaus.blogspot.com/2010/05/phnom-penh-cambodias-beautiful-capitol.html):

[image]

Clearly this (non-) punctuation (along with the aggressive-looking formatting) has a very different, almost passive-aggressive, effect than

> Would you please show your respect ...?

What is the effect by which we modify the meaning of a question by changing it syntactically into a statement?

Comment: There is no syntactic change here. It is the same thing.

Comment: @tchrist Can you explain?

Comment: A question is still a question no matters its punctuation.  After all, does speech have any punctuation.

Comment: @tchrist But doesn't it sound quite different internally if you inflect it like a statement? (think flight attendant question-commands)

Comment: Your sign is not a declarative statement; it is a request— which counts as a question.

Comment: @tchrist Not according to [English Club](http://www.englishclub.com/writing/punctuation-question-mark.htm): 6. Many polite requests or instructions are made in the form of a question. But because they are not really questions, they do not take a question mark:

Could you please send me your catalogue.
Would all first-class and business-class passengers now start boarding. RHK Webster's specifies that a question is: a sentence in an interrogative form addressed to someone _in order to get information in reply_. (emphasis mine)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not per my education.

Comment: @tchrist I don't accept 'per your education' as as valid an authority as published or online authorities such as Webster's. I'd be far happier with less dogmatic statements such as 'which many would regard as a question'. I don't. Neither do the English Club writers.

Comment: I agree that the question mark may be used to signal a difference. 'Can you open the window.' may have a different meaning from 'Can you open the window?' I couldn't call the with-question-mark choice wrong for the request rather than the question, but quite a few 'authorities' license the period instead, eg [Pearson Education](http://wps.prenhall.com/wps/media/objects/1382/1415230/thill_exbus_2ce_ch12_ee.pdf) Polite request worded like question: Could you please return this copy with your corrections by 
November 1.

Comment: @F.E.  The idea of a 'verbless clause' is not acceptable to many, so '... which [constitute] a major type of clause' is not either. Those who do accept the 'verbless clause' usually demand an obvious true clause from which it derives.

Comment: “Please kindly” is not English; is fawning sycophancy.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a question, it's a request, which is not the same thing.

Phrasing a request like a question is a kind of politeness that uses phrasing ("would you") associated with questions to tone down the commanding nature of telling someone to do something.

A true question requests an answer. Here, no answer is expected; it's behavior that's requested.

"Can you go to the store for me?" is a question, but, "Please go to the store for me" is a request that doesn't get a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a simple error to use "Would you" without a trailing question mark. I can’t think of an instance in which that would feel correct, though that’s only my intuition. "Please kindly show your respect..." is perfectly fine.

Therefore I don’t think there is any particular syntactic effect at work aside from the technique of intentional error.